# How to fix logic errors in my binary search tree?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

so I have been trying to get an old c++ binary search tree program of mine to work.It compiles and runs but I do not get the results I would expect. If I insert c,d,a,b in that order and try to remove c, my remove function skips the if conditionals that find in order successors. Why are those 2 else if conditionals skipped?

Also it is compiled using gcc.

```
  Node::Node(string nodeItem,
           int nodeLine){
    item=nodeItem;
    vector<int> tempVector;
    tempVector.push_back(nodeLine);
    lines=tempVector;
    leftPtr = NULL;
    rightPtr = NULL;
}


// recursive method for finding node containing the word
Node* BST::find(string data, Node *curr) {

    if(curr==NULL) {
        cout << data << " is not in the tree" << endl;
        return curr;

    }
    if(curr->getItem().compare("theplaceholder")==0){
        return curr;
    }
    string tempItem = curr->getItem();
    //this if statement is if I am inserting a word that is already in the tree
    // or if I am removing the word from the tree
    if(data.compare(tempItem)==0){
        return curr;
    }
    else if(data.compare(tempItem)<0){
        return find(data,curr->getLeftPtr());
    }
    else{
        return find(data, curr->getRightPtr());
    }

}


void BST::insert(string data, int fromLine) {
    Node *curr;


    curr=find(data, root); 


    if(curr!=NULL && curr->getItem().compare("theplaceholder")==0){

        curr->setData(data);

        curr->addLines(fromLine);
    }


    if(curr==NULL){

        // I want to point to a nonNull node.
        // I am making a new node and having curr point to that instead of NULL
        //then I set it to



        curr=new Node(data, fromLine);


        cout <<curr->getItem() << endl;

        vector<int> foundLines=curr->getNodeLines();
        //cout<< "The word " <<curr->getItem() << " can be found in lines ";
        if(foundLines.empty())
            cout << "foundLines is empty";
        int size=foundLines.size();
        for(int count=0; count<size; count++){

            //cout << foundLines[count] << ", ";
        }

    }

    if(curr->getItem()==data){
        curr->addLines(fromLine);
    }
}
// remove method I am trying to check for in order successors to swap with the deleted node.
void BST::remove(string data) {
    Node *curr=root;


    Node *temp=find(data, curr);
    if(temp==NULL){
        cout << " nothing to remove" << endl;
    }
    else if(temp->getRightPtr()!=NULL){

        curr=temp->getRightPtr();
        cout << curr->getItem() << endl;
        while(curr->getLeftPtr()!=NULL){
            curr=curr->getLeftPtr();
            cout << curr->getItem() << endl;
        }
        temp->setData(curr->getItem());

        temp->setLines(curr->getNodeLines());
        delete curr;
        curr=NULL;
    }
    else if(temp->getLeftPtr()!=NULL){
        cout <<"if !temp->getLeftPtr" << endl;
        curr=temp->getLeftPtr();
        cout << curr->getItem() << endl;
        while(curr->getRightPtr()!=NULL){
            curr=curr->getRightPtr();
            cout << curr->getItem() << endl;
        }
        temp->setData(curr->getItem());

        temp->setLines(curr->getNodeLines());
        delete curr;
        curr=NULL;
    }
    else{
        cout <<"else delete temp" << endl;
        delete temp;
        temp=NULL;

    }

}
```

Comment: Does no one use indentation any more?

Comment: First off, you do not need to use the `this` pointer when in the scope of a class method. Take them out.

Comment: I just use eclipse's auto-indentation. Specific formatting may have been lost when I copy pasted it in here and tried to make all the code gray.

Comment: Are you trying to search a binary tree or are you trying to write a priority queue?

Comment: Try pinning down the problem, rather than pasting a huge wall of code.

Comment: You just need to indent it an extra four characters in Eclipse before you copy. As an aside, your promote replacement logic looks incomplete - in the right-branch case you delete the curr node but you don't clear the right-pointer from the previous node that owned it. Nor do you cope with the case where that right-most node had a left child that now needs to be promoted into its place.

Comment: `"my remove function skips the if conditionals that find in order successors. Why are those 2 else if conditionals skipped?"`

Possibly because the first `if` condition is being met?

Comment: @thomas, I am attempting to write a bst. So I was trying to write a tree where left child<parent and right child>parent (alphabetical order).

Comment: @doug, when I insert c,d,a,b I would imagine c is the root, d is the right child of c, a is left child of c, b is right child of a. So if I try to remove c, then my find function finds the node for c, if shouldn't be NULL, then the next 2 conditionals check for in order successors, and the final else statement should only cover when node c has no children. When I run my program, it seems that if I try to remove a node not in the tree, I successfully arrive at the first conditional of the remove function and if I try to remove any other node in the tree, I end up in the final else statement.

Comment: @LostNitrogen: Then your two `else if` conditionals are never evaluating to true. You need to debug, debug, and then debug some more. Setup some breakpoints, insert items into the tree. **DRAW** the tree on paper, and follow the logic step-by-step to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: well I had already done some of that for many hours because I had expected this kind of response(I added cout statements at multiple points in the tree and then inserted items, and drew the tree) . I guess stackoverflow is just not the place for me to ask for help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @LostNitrogen: Stack Overflow is the *perfect* place to ask for help. You just need to format your question a little better. Remove code that is not relevant to your problem (you posted quite a bit). Add some of the output you got with your `cout` statements during your hours of debugging. I would suggest you display output for 1) Create the tree. 2) Do about 3 or 4 insertions. 3) Do a deletion. Show output for *each* step.

Comment: @Doug Ramsey, I will try and clean up my post. I originally added the whole bst implementation because I thought people would want all the code. After it is more easily understandable I will post output information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this line

```
else if(temp->getRightPtr()!=NULL){
```

never succeeds is that you never set the right pointer on any node - getRightPtr can only return null. If you'd examined the state of your tree in the debugger after you'd built it or if you stepped through the insert function you'd probably have seen this. The problems are:

- your find function doesn't return null if the node isn't in the tree, whereas your insert function expects it will
- your insert function needs to locate the position in the tree where this node should be - either through fixing the find function or on its own, then create a new node AND add a reference to it from the parent node, on either the left or right side as appropriate
- your insert function appears the line number to the first-inserted node twice: once when you overwrite the placeholder and once at the end of insert (rather than use a placeholder here I'd probably have initialised `root` to be null and instead set root = curr when you create the first node)
- your remove function needs to do more work when promoting the highest node from the left-hand branch; it needs to

  - correctly clean up that node from it's previous parent - at the moment you delete the object but leave any dangling pointers alone
  - promote any children of that node before you move it to take its previous slot

i.e.

```
      D                                       C                           
     / \                                     / \
    A   E  remove 'D'                       A   E
     \       => 'C' is highest on left       \
      C         but need to move B to C       B
     /
    B
```